# Angular velocity of a rock

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

Here is the question: 
A student ties a 500g rock to a 1.0 m long string and swings it around her head in a horizontal circle. At what angular velocity in rpm does the string tilt down at a $10^\circ$ angle.

I have done the following steps so far:

1) $\sum F_x = mv^2$ since there is centripetal acceleration

$T\cos θ = m\omega^2r$

$T = \frac{m\omega^2r}{\cos θ}$

2) $\sum F_y = 0$

$T\sinθ - mg = 0$

$\frac{m\omega^2rsinθ}{\cos θ} = mg$

$\omega^2=\frac{g\cosθ}{\sinθr}$

Since $r = \cosθL$

$\omega = \sqrt{-\frac{g}{\sinθL}}$

$\omega = 4.24\,\text{rad/s}$

$\omega= 40.53\,\text{rpm}$

The answer is supposed to be 71.7 rpm and I do not know where I went wrong.

Comment: $\theta = 10^\circ$ satisfy the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you just plugged in the numbers wrong. Your procedure seems to be correct.
Plugging in $-9.8m/s^2$ for g, 10º for theta, and 1.0m for L into the final expression for  that you provided,  comes out to be 7.51 rad/s. This is equal to 71.7 rpm, as desired.